# How to create a timestep size in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

So this is the kind of a question that I have been given.

In a Jupyter notebook create a pd.DataFrame.
Index is a date time index
15 minutes time-step-size
Create 500 columns of data.
The values should be floats.
The range for the random numbers should at least -1000 to + 1000, but range for each column should be randomly generated as well.

The question is I have so far not been able to produce anything regarding time step size. Is it the same as frequency? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it means frequency. Check out the pandas docs for [pd.date_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

The freq parameter will be `'15T'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1000, 1000,size=(1, 500)))
df.index = pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=len(df), freq='0.25H')
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27301371).